# Python set to list

Tags: python, list, set

How can I convert a set to a list in Python? Using

```
a = set(["Blah", "Hello"])
a = list(a)
```

doesn't work. It gives me:

```
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Comment: The above works for me on Python 2.7.

Comment: if you named another variable in your code `set` change it because you are shadowing the builtin function `set` .

Comment: Works for me with Python 2.6.6. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: @mouad No, the string in parentheses in a `TypeError` is the name of the *type*, not the variable name

Comment: @phihag: That very True :) +1

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7 as well, and it sure doesn't work.

Comment: tried the situation in a fresh virtualenv environment?

Comment: @Judge John Deed: You did `list = some_set` somewhere. Add `print list` before you call it.

Comment: I hit this problem while debugging in PDB where 'list' is overridden as a PDB command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a set to a list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593979/how-to-convert-a-set-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 271):

Your code *does* work (tested with cpython 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2):

```
>>> a = set(["Blah", "Hello"])
>>> a = list(a) # You probably wrote a = list(a()) here or list = set() above
>>> a
['Blah', 'Hello']
```

Check that you didn't overwrite `list` by accident:

```
>>> assert list == __builtins__.list
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted this exact code in IDLE; I get the error.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dir(set)` and `print set`?

Comment: `['and', 'class', 'cmp', 'contains', 'delattr', 'doc', 'eq', 'format', 'ge', 'getattribute', 'gt', 'hash', 'iand', 'init', 'ior', 'isub', 'iter', 'ixor', 'le', 'len', 'lt', 'ne', 'new', 'or', 'rand', 'reduce', 'reduce_ex', 'repr', 'ror', 'rsub', 'rxor', 'setattr', 'sizeof', 'str', 'sub', 'subclasshook', 'xor', 'add', 'clear', 'copy', 'difference', 'difference_update', 'discard', 'intersection', 'intersection_update', 'isdisjoint', 'issubset', 'issuperset', 'pop', 'remove', 'symmetric_difference', 'symmetric_difference_update', 'union', 'update']` (removed __ because of char limit)

Comment: @Judge John Deed At which line do you get the error? Your `set` looks fine.

Comment: try Set instead of set : REF: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 76):

You've shadowed the builtin set by accidentally using it as a variable name, here is a simple way to replicate your error

```
>>> set=set()
>>> set=set()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

The first line rebinds set to an *instance* of set. The second line is trying to *call* the instance which of course fails.

Here is a less confusing version using different names for each variable. Using a fresh interpreter

```
>>> a=set()
>>> b=a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Hopefully it is obvious that calling `a` is an error

Answer (score 29):

before you write `set(XXXXX)`
you have used "set" as a variable
e.g.

```
set = 90 #you have used "set" as an object
…
…
a = set(["Blah", "Hello"])
a = list(a)
```

Answer (score 17):

This will work:

```
>>> t = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
>>> print list(set(t))
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

However, if you have used "list" or "set" as a variable name you will get the:

```
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

eg:

```
>>> set = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
>>> print list(set(set))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Same error will occur if you have used "list" as a variable name.

Answer (score 9):

```
s = set([1,2,3])
print [ x for x in iter(s) ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code works with Python 3.2.1 on Win7 x64

```
a = set(["Blah", "Hello"])
a = list(a)
type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using combination of map and lambda functions:

```
aList = map( lambda x: x, set ([1, 2, 6, 9, 0]) )
```

It is very convenient approach if you have a set of numbers in string and you want to convert it to list of integers:

```
aList = map( lambda x: int(x), set (['1', '2', '3', '7', '12']) )
```