# Linting variable annotation typo from PEP 526

Tags: python, lint, mypy, pep

I just had to debug a problem in production that boils down to the following behavior.

What I should have typed:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> a: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(StringIO('a,b,c\n1,2,3'))
>>> isinstance(a, pd.DataFrame)
True
```

What I actually typed:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(StringIO('a,b,c\n1,2,3'))
>>> isinstance(a, pd.DataFrame)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

This was hard to track, because the `isinstance()` check was added months after the typo was made. The original code worked because `pd.DataFrame` wasn't used anywhere else in the scope.

Is there any way to catch this nasty typo? `mypy` doesn't see a problem with it.

---

Edit: the original question used `list` instead of `pd.DataFrame`, but as pointed out by some users, both this [flake8 plugin](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-builtins/) and [pylint W0622](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/variables/W0622.html) can detect redefined builtins.

Comment: [Flake8 Builtins plugin](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-builtins/): "Check for python builtins being used as variables or parameters."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lint for variable names such as 'len' (built-in functions/reserved words etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609715/lint-for-variable-names-such-as-len-built-in-functions-reserved-words-etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to protect built-ins in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191277/is-there-a-way-to-protect-built-ins-in-python)

Comment: You're all correct, but the error can still happen with non-bultin types. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
pip install pandas-stubs
```

And mypy should start failing with:

```
error: Cannot assign to a type
```

## Long answer

You are correct in assuming that mypy should have blocked this. But the problem is that the pandas project does not includes type information yet. By now (March 2021) the pandas team has it's own stub project in progress see https://pypi.org/project/pandas-stubs/.