# Convert to Dictionary Values that Contains a Set to a List

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to convert a set inside a list like

```
x = [set(['Halo', 'Bye'])]
```

into a list:

```
['Halo', 'Bye']
```

However when I typed list(x), the result still shows

```
[set(['Halo', 'Bye'])]
```

Is there a way to do this?

I have been looking at various Stackoverflow resources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593979/how-to-convert-a-set-to-a-list-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828722/python-set-to-list) for a solution but nothing works.

Comment: If you are using python 3.x, just use tuple unpacking. `x = [*set(['Halo', 'Bye'])]`

Comment: @Nf4r that's not tuple unpacking, but that works.

Comment: I know that u can use it on any iterable, but I was just used to call it tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a list already, but the set you that are trying to convert is an element of the list `x`.
So, do:

```
print (list(x[0]))
```

instead of just `list(x)` as the set is the first and the only element in the list `x`.

Comment: It works. I didn't realize that I still need to call the first element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[item for set_ in x for item in set_]
```

This will flatten a list of sets (or a list of lists) into just a list