# Convert a set to a list in Python 2.7.8

Tags: list, python-2.7, set

Trying to adapt further from this question on stackoverflow:

[How to convert a set to a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593979/how-to-convert-a-set-to-a-list-in-python)

I have been trying to solve [this riddle on interactivepython.org](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ControlStructures.html) The riddle is exactly on the end of the page and it goes like...

We have a list, for eg `list1 = ['cat','dog','rabbit']` and now using list comprehension (strictly list comprehension), we have to create a list of each alphabet in the each word in list1 and the resulting list should not contain duplicates.

So the expected answer is something like:

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Its alright even if the sequence is not maintained.

Now first to create a list of all characters, used:

```
print [word[i] for word in list1 for i in range(len(word))]
```

and it gives output

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

This includes duplicates as well

so I then created this into set as sets do not contain duplicates:

```
print set([word[i] for word in list1 for i in range(len(word))])
```

output:

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'o', 'r', 't'])
```

however this returns a set not a list and the same can be verified by:

```
type(set([word[i] for word in list1 for i in range(len(word))]))
```

output:

```
<type 'set'>
```

Now, in the video on the above given link of interactivepython.org the guy just puts encloses the entire thing after `print` in `list()` as follows:

```
print list(set([word[i] for word in list1 for i in range(len(word))]))
```

and he gets the result output in list, however I don't get the same when I try using idle that uses python 2.7.8. It instead gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    print list(set([word[i] for word in list1 for i in range(len(word))]))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I think this is may be because interactive python uses Python 3 for its tutorials. So is this merely a difference between Python 3 and Python 2.7?

Also, how can I achieve similar output using Python 2.7.8

Thanks

Comment: I'd just go for `list(set().union(*list1))` if that's not completely against the rules - that'll work on 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 2):

We can use list(set) to convert set to list in python 2.7

```
>>> a=set([1,2,3])
>>> a
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b=list(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

I think python 3 is also having same features

Answer (score 0):

All Python versions support creating a list via the syntax `list(<iterable>)`, so your specific Python version is not the cause of the error.

I think you've done a similar mistake to that in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594009/3903832) to the linked question you provided, i.e. in your interactive shell you defined a variable with the name `list` which shadows the built-in type `list`.

For example, on Python 2.7.6:

```
>>> list({1, 2, 3}) # successfully convert a set to a list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list = []       # shadow the built-in type list
>>> list({1, 2, 3}) # this fails since list no longer references the built-in type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Try exiting your shell and re-entering it, executing the same commands, and see if they work.

---

On an unrelated note, you can further improve your list generation from this:

```
[word[i] for word in list1 for i in range(len(word))]
```

to this:

```
[letter for word in list1 for letter in word]
```

since iterating over a string returns its characters one by one. In fact, this is also the underlying logic behind @JonClements astute solution:

```
list(set().union(*list1))
```