# Remove an item in one set that has an item containing the other sets item

Tags: python

My whole application is a little `sitemap-Scraper`, I feed it the root link, from here it will scan the site for more links, and then scrape those sites also for more links, kinda like a sitemap-gen just more verbose. **The bigger picture** is, is that there are sites containing *youtube,facebook,google etc*. These sites can lead to a further eternity and put my app into a limbo-chain, thus I decided I'll feed it a **blocker** so we can remove those *bigger websites*

I have a file called `blocked_sites.txt` in which i have:

```
facebook
youtube
```

And I have a `set` in which I have:

```
'facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold'
```

So, what I want to do, is :

1. Compare Both *lists* items to one another
2. Check if *urls*-item **CONTAINS** *blocked_sites* item
3. *Remove That item if it contains BLOCKED item*

**Point 1&2 I got done But the third one is a gotcha**, this is what I preemptively tried:

```
 # For every url in urls
 for url in urls:
   # For every blocker inside blocked
   for blocker in blocked:      
      # If URL contains BLOCKER
      if blocker in url:
         # Remove THAT URL
         urls.remove(url)
         print('removed: ' + url)
print(urls)
```

**The problem is** that I can't really modify a set while iterating through it at the same time. So what are my options?

Heres what I thought:

1. Take the `URL` that **DOESNT** contain blocker and copy it to another set
   --This seems a bit bulky, I mean, we would then have to deal with the *urls,blocker, new_urls* and doesn't seem as much of a good idea, especially if I am constantly feeding more and more links to the old list, doesn't seem very memory effecient
2. Let's try and convert them into a list!
   --Hey! It worked! for like only 3 items?
   --On further look, a [set already is a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593979/how-to-convert-a-set-to-a-list-in-python)
   yet, I got an error when I was using `{ 'item' }` as my set as opposed to `[ 'item' ]`?

Okay so take these first sets:

```
urls = {'facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold'}
blocked = {'facebook'}
>> Set changed during iteration
```

alrighty, let's do it this-way:

```
urls = ['facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold']
blocked = ['facebook']
>>> Removed: facebook
```

Yay it worked!

What if we add more blockers like so:

```
urls = ['facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold']
blocked = ['facebook', 'youtube']
>>>Removed: facebook
   ['youtube.com', 'gold']
```

That's strange! For some reason, it can only take off one blocker?

**How do I get to the *gold***?

Comment: `for url in list(urls):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a list/set's content during iteration is typically a recipe for disaster. In almost all cases, it is better to construct a new list/set instead of operating in place. This is very simple with a comprehension:

```
urls = ['facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold']
blocked = ['facebook', 'youtube']

urls = [url for url in urls if not any(blocker in url for blocker in blocked)]
print(urls)
# ['gold']
```

With sets:

```
urls = {'facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold'}
blocked = {'facebook', 'youtube'}

urls = {url for url in urls if not any(blocker in url for blocker in blocked)}
print(urls)
# {'gold'}
```

However, do note that iterating through sets is quite slow and the option with lists is probably faster.

Answer (score 2):

We can extend your approach a bit further to achieve what you want solely using set operations.

```
found = set()
urls = {'facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'gold'}
blocked = {'facebook', 'youtube'}

for url in urls:
    for blocker in blocked:
        if blocker in url:
            found.add(url)

urls.difference(found)

{'gold'}
```